# Ordering a set of sub categories within a category list from sql database

Tags: php, database, loops, mysqli, while-loop

I've got this code and I don't know how to order my query

```
function get_All_Categories(){
//new instance of mysqli
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    //if it doesn't work give an error
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
    }
    $queryCats ="SELECT Catid, Catname
                 FROM ProductCats
                 ORDER BY Catid";
    $querySubCats ="SELECT Subcatname, Parentid
                    FROM ProductSubCats, ProductCats
                    WHERE ProductSubCats.Parentid = ProductCats.Catid
                    ORDER BY Subcatname;";
    if ($catResults = $mysqli->query($queryCats)){
        if (!$catResults) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        else{
            $subCatResults = $mysqli->query($querySubCats);
        }
        while ($rows = $catResults->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<div class = "categoryCluster">';
            echo '<a href="../index.php?Cat='.$rows["Catname"].'">'.$rows["Catname"].'</a>';
            echo '<br>';
            while($rowsSub = $subCatResults->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<div class="subCategoryCluster">';
                echo '&emsp;'.'<a href="../index.php?Cat='.$rows["Catname"].'&'.'Subcat='.$rowsSub["Subcatname"].'">'.$rowsSub["Subcatname"].'</a>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Which displays this output:

```
Header 1
 Subcat 1
 Subcat 2
 OtherSubcat 1
Header 2
Header 3
Header 4
Header 5
Header 6
```

But my problem is that subcat 1 and subcat 2 have the parentid of 1, which conforms to header 1, however othersubcat 1 has the parentid of 5. Which actually conforms to header 5.
Yeh in my loop it is displaying right after the other 2.

Now I know why this is wrong, it is because the while loop in the while loop is ordering it to appear last, and sticking it in there.

But I have absolutely no idea how to rework this so that it would display:

```
Header 1
 Subcat 1
 Subcat 2
Header 2
Header 3
Header 4
Header 5
 OtherSubcat 1
Header 6
```

Sample table:

```
>     ProductSubCats
>     Subcatid  |  Subcatname   | Parentid
>     1         | Subcat 1      | 1
>     2         | Subcat 2      | 1
>     3         | Othersubcat 3 | 5
> 
> 
> 
> ProductCats
>     Cat id   |   Catname
>     1        | Header 1
>     2        | Header 2
>     3        | Header 3
>     4        | Header 4
>     5        | Header 5
>     6        | Header 6
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, following off what @Pasha Bitz said.

Try the following:

```
$categories = array();
        $sub_categories = array();  
        while ($rows = $catResults->fetch_assoc()) {
            $categories[$rows['Catid']] = $rows['Catname'];
        }
        while($rows = $subCatResults->fetch_assoc()){
            if (!isset($sub_categories[$rows['Parentid']])) {
                $sub_categories[$rows['Parentid']] = array();
            }
            $sub_categories[$rows['Parentid']][] = $rows['Subcatname'];
        }
        foreach ($categories as $cat_id => $name) {
            echo '<div class = "categoryCluster">';
            echo '<a href="../index.php?Cat='.$name.'">'.$name.'</a>';
            echo '<br>';
            if (isset($sub_categories[$cat_id])) {
                foreach($sub_categories[$cat_id] as $cat_id => $sub_cat_name) {
                    echo '<div class="subCategoryCluster">';
                    echo '&emsp;'.'<a href="../index.php?Cat='.$name.'&'.'Subcat='.$sub_cat_name.'">'.$sub_cat_name.'</a>';
                    echo '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
```

That should resolve this for you, study the code so you understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the database query loops from the display loops.
First fetch all of your data, for both queries and store it in two associative arrays.
To make the second step easier, structure your sub-categories array as follows:

- Key - parent id
- Value - array of all sub-categories with this parent id

Second, loop over the categories array. For each element:

- Print out the category name
- Loop over the sub-categories with this parent id - print them

Like this:

```
//assuming you populated $catResults and $subCatResults as in your example
$categories = array();
$sub_categories = array();

while($row = $catResults->fetch_assoc()) {
 $categories[$row['Catid']] = $row['Catname'];
}
while($row = $subCatResults->fetch_assoc()) {
 if (!isset($sub_categories[$row['Parentid']])) {
  $sub_categories[$row['Parentid']] = array();
 }
 $sub_categories[$row['Parentid']][] = $row['Subcatname'];
}

//display
foreach ($categories as $cat_id => $name) {
 echo $name;
 if (isset($sub_categories[$cat_id])) {
  foreach($sub_categories[$cat_id] => $sub_cat_name) {
   echo '  ' . $sub_cat_name;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, just testing that now but I am getting an error on the line:
foreach($sub_categories[$cat_id] => $sub_cat_name) {

Comment: Change to foreach($sub_categories[$cat_id] as $sub_cat_name) {